# X-Frame-Option with YouTube in Ruby on Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, video, youtube, same-origin-policy, x-frame-options

I'm trying to display a YouTube video within an `iframe` in my Ruby on Rails app. The video, with a url like `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XIv_JOmtgSA`, for example, doesn't show on the page and I get the following error:

`Refused to display 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XIv_JOmtgSA' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.`

I've already tried some things, like calling this on the controller:

```
def allow_iframe_requests
   response.headers.delete('X-Frame-Options')
end
```

But I can't get it to display the video. I've tried an *Incognito Window* in Google Chrome too.

Comment: You're using the wrong url. Use embed url provided on every youtube vice page.

Comment: I know that. But my app's users insert a YouTube url that could be like the one I said above. How to show the video on the page, if that?

Comment: Fix the url. You probably just need to change `/watch/` to `/embed/`

Comment: Maybe that works. Adding `v` in the video url does it, like this: `https://www.youtube.com/v/watch?v=XIv_JOmtgSA`. But how would I do it to change the urls in my controller `Create` action? Where I receive a string `:video` (in params) with the url?

Comment: It's data so you should do it on a model.

Comment: I don't have much experience in Rails. Could you write an answer about how to do that?

Comment: It would have to be and answer about how to use Rails. Better head to guides.rubyonrails.org and read a few chapters before continuing. It's not long and will allow you to grasp basic MVC, Rails and web development concepts in general.

Comment: I just don't understand why to do that in the Model, and how.